# The kakao autoresponder API has problems accessing the keyboard

Tags: python, django, chatbot

I want to make chatbot using kakaotalk.
but have problems accessing the keyboard.
I use python,pycharm and django.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'globalHaksik',
 ]
```

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('globalHaksik/', include('globalHaksik.urls')),
    ]
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('keyboard/', views.keyboard),
   ]
```

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def keyboard(request):
    return JsonResponse({
        'type': 'buttons',
        'buttons': ['오늘', '내일']
    })
```

KakaoTalk shows this error.

```
Required*
keyboard Fail 415
wrong keyboard initialization
```

When I use view.py like this, it works fine on the internet.

```
def keyboard(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

why is this errer?